# Cut, Copy and Paste as JMenuItems

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jmenu, jmenuitem

I have two JTextAreas and would like to implement cut, copy, and paste menu items.  I am aware of JTextArea.cut and other methods but cannot figure out how to figure out where (in which JTextArea) the user has selected text, and or placed their cursor.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Actions provided by the editor kit. For example:

```
JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem( new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction() );
```

Answer (score 1):

For the selected text, take a look at [`JTextArea#getSelectedText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29)

For the caret position, take a look at [`JTextArea#getCaretPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29)